# I am using C# + ASP.NET Core to create a web application that needs to fetch a list of printers from a Print server or from the web hosted IIS server

Tags: c#, web, printing, asp.net-core-mvc

This code gets the local printers from the PC that runs the application. Only works if the web application runs locally from Visual Studio. But does not work when the web application is hosted in IIS server.

```
public async Task<List<URLDTO>> GetPrinterNames()
{
    List<string> printerNames = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>().ToList();
    List<URLDTO> print = new List<URLDTO>();

    var count = printerNames.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        URLDTO addprint = new URLDTO();
        addprint.Printers = printerNames[i];
        print.Add(addprint);
    }

    return print;
}
```

Is there a way to grab the local printers that the web app is accessed from or can it grab the list of printers from the web hosted IIS server?